# Android RadioButton inside child recyclerView's single selection and uncheck is not working,

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, radio-button, adapter

I have recyclerview in parentAdapter , which have three different layouts multiple-choice(Title & RadioButtons), Comment (Title & EditText) and Boolean(Title & RadioButtons(Y/N)). These layouts set based on API response. Now boolean and Multichoice have child-recyclerview with seperate child-adapter contains radioButton, expected a single selection but uncheck and single selection is not happening as expected.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2F5g.png)

this is parentAdapter onBindViewHolder,

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: InspectionAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val model: QueryList = item.get(position)

    if(model.QueryType.equals("YES / NO")){
        holder.booleanQueryTitleLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        holder.booleanQueryBodyLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        holder.stringLayout.visibility = View.GONE
        holder.mcLayout.visibility = View.GONE
        holder.tvBooleanQueryName.text = model.QuestionName
        
        val booleanArray: List<String> = model.QueryType.split("/")
        var booleanList1 : List<String>?=null
        booleanList1 = booleanArray
        booleanList1 = booleanList1.toCollection(ArrayList())

        if(booleanList1.size>0) {
            holder.rvBooleanQuery.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            booleanAdapter = context?.let { BooleanAdapter(it, booleanList1, position, item[position].QueryType) }!!
            holder.rvBooleanQuery.adapter = booleanAdapter
            holder.rvBooleanQuery.setHasFixedSize(true);
            holder.rvBooleanQuery.setLayoutManager(holder.rvBooleanQuery.layoutManager);
            booleanAdapter!!.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        }
    }
    else if(model.QueryType.equals("string")){ //Comment Type
    
    }
    else { // Multi-choice Type
    //multi-choice recyclerView
    }
    
    }
```

And this is onBindViewHolder() of childAdapter (Boolean case)

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BooleanAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    Log.e(TAG,"booleanAdapterName"+ item.get(position))
    holder.booleanQueryName.setChecked(position == mSelectedItem)

    holder.booleanQueryName.text = item.get(position)


    if (mSelectedItem == position) {
        holder.booleanQueryName.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        holder.booleanQueryName.setChecked(false);
    }
    holder.booleanRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {
            group, checkedId ->
        this.mSelectedItem = holder.getAdapterPosition()
        if (holder.booleanQueryName.isChecked) {
            mSelectedItem = position
        } else {
            mSelectedItem = -1
        }
    })
    holder.booleanQueryNameYes.setOnClickListener {
       // if(selectedPosition == position){
        hideSoftKeyboard(context, it)
        mSelectedItem = holder.getAdapterPosition()

        if(holder.booleanQueryNameYes.isChecked){
            holder.booleanQueryNameYes.setChecked(true)
            holder.booleanQueryNameYes.isChecked = true
            Toast.makeText(context, "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        } else {
            holder.booleanQueryNameYes.setChecked(false)
            holder.booleanQueryNameYes.isChecked = false
            Toast.makeText(context, "No", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

    }

}
```

Tried last adapter-pos-tion that selected and tried to do uncheck in if condition,, but that doesnt work. how to achieve this?

Comment: Check my answer again I have edited the explanation behind radiobutton uncheck not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than setting any RadioButton to `false` always use `clearCheck()` method, that will remove the value of radiobutton and set it to *null like the state it was at the creation of radiobutton time.*

This way it will work properly reason behind this is that setting radiobutton to false make it in `unchecked state`. Unchecked state is exact opposite of checked state but what you need is radio button to be in `null state` to make it `checkable` properly once it was checked.